# Laravel mysql query shut down server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm currently building an application with Laravel php Framework using Eloquent ORM. Im just trying to optimize this query because it takes very long time to display results.

Here's the code, How can i optimze it?

```
$messages = DB::table('mp as m1')
            ->select(DB::raw('m1.id as id, m1.user_id, m1.titre, m1.titremd5, content, m1.vu, users.name, users.slug, users.avatar, m1.horodateur, m1.id_conversation'))
            ->join('users', 'm1.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->whereRaw('id_conversation IN (SELECT id FROM conversations_in WHERE user_id = '.Auth::user()->id.' AND visible=1 AND horodateur_fin = "") AND m1.id = (SELECT MAX(mp.id) FROM mp WHERE mp.id_conversation = m1.id_conversation)')
            ->orderBy('m1.id', 'DESC')
            ->paginate(10);
```

I have no idea why this work so slow and it takes like 10 seconds to load page. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: I think your database size is too large and you can use order by so due to this reason sql filter all rows and your query take much time

Comment: How much record take in your `mp`,`user` and `conversations_in` tables?

Comment: mp contains 258264 records

Comment: Try installing the laravel debugbar and select the query tab which will show optimisation suggestions for any queries being run

Comment: So as per SQL stander when you use oderby condition then it's filter all rows of table (here ... 258264) and get result as per your query (here get 10 rows) so due to this reason query take much time. So you can make query  first get 10 record and after  set order by condition

Comment: Thanks. I'll edit accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Add db indexes for columns: horodateur_fin, visible